# How can i setup Visual Studio Code for simple C programming?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Completely new to programming and will start a mechanical engineering course this year and we have to set up a C enviroment with Visual Studio Code at home.

Was following the instructions so i downloaded and installed MinGW and set the path in Windows. Tested this with the cmd console. Then installed VSC and C/C++ extension and i was supposed to test it with the "Hello World!" program but i get an error message every time:

launch: program 'D:\folder\build\Debug\outDebug' does not exist

Was searching and found that it had something to do with the launch.json config file so i have rewritten it with the suggested ${workspaceFolder} instead of the \ pathing but i get the same error.

Comment: Microsoft has a full guide here - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw - you should start there. The guide also explains how to install proper C compilers on Windows.

Comment: Or use gcc in your wsl distro - [microsoft guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl).